# Showing Hebrew Characters in Eclipse's Android Graphical Layout

Tags: android, eclipse, hebrew

Anybody knows how I can convince Eclipse to show Hebrew characters in the Graphical Layout? When I add Hebrew strings to the resources, they show up fine in the text editor, on the emulator and on the phone, but inside the Graphical Layout window all I see are rectangles.

Itay